# How to get the Youtube vid ID from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

I would like to get the youtube video id from my JSON file. The id will be extract by using a regex function. 
When I pass in `id` as a parameter of the youtube function `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` I will receive an error: `Uncaught TypeError: YT.Player is not a function`.

My regex function:

```
regexVideoId: function(url) {
        var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
        var match = url.match(regExp);
        console.log(match[7]);
        onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(match[7]);
        // return (match&&match[7].length==11)? match[7] : false;
    },
```

Youtube function:

```
var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(id) {
        player = new YT.Player('youtube-video', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: id,
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
```

Call the regex function and send the youtube URL: `regexVideoId(data.youtube);` 
I make use of the Youtube Javascript API. The regex function works, it will extract the video from it's id. Only by passing the `video id` to the function  `onYoutubeIframeAPIReady` is not working and gives me the error of `is not a function`.

What does I do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just a question: If you have a valid JSON, why are you using regex to parse JSON?

Comment: So the user can place the full url to the JSON (later in the backend) and the URL will extract the video id from it's URL. @Tivie

Comment: Anyway, can you make a fiddle? The problem might be that the library is not being loaded or something

Comment: I can try to create a JSfiddle, only I use multiple scripts in multiple files that are linked together... But I will try to create one!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq9rjbouBlY&t=23 - The parse function works, I get `Sq9rjbouBlY` has the id. Only by passing it to the `onYoutubeIframeAPIReady` I get the error.

Comment: Check my answer... your probably calling `onYoutubeIframeAPIReady` before youtube API library is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide enough code so this is a bit of guessing work.

However, it seems the problem is that you're calling `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` directly, probably before the youtube API is fully loaded. (the example provided in [Youtube API Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples) uses async loading)

You can fix that by inverting the logic. Instead of calling `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` explicitly in `regexVideoId` function, you make `YT.Player` constructor call the `regexVideoId` function instead:

```
function regexVideoId(url) {
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    return match[7];
}

//...

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('youtube-video', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: videoId: regexVideoId(theUrl),
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
```

Check this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juws6gak/)

Comment: @sln yeah, I copy/pasted from OP code, forgot to remove